# Unable to use Box API Enterprise API with OAuth2 authenticated app

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

What I understand is Enterprise API from Box works only with server-server JWT auth and not like OAuth2 based authentication.
Box integrations which haveOAuth2 based authentication support only Content API and not the Enterprise API.

Is there way to have OAuth & Ebterprise API at the same time? (I essentially want to manage users & groups any third party enterprise)

Any thoughts/pointers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I understand is Enterprise API from Box works only with server-server JWT auth and not like OAuth2 based authentication.

This is not correct, though I can see how you could arrive at that understanding. You can work with the Box Enterprise API using traditional 3-Legged OAuth. In fact, for many years 3-Legged OAuth was the *only* way to work with the Box API.

In order for a 3-Legged OAuth access token to make Enterprise API calls:

1. The appropriate Enterprise scopes must be selected in the app configuration.
2. The token must have been issued for a user with enterprise admin/co-admin privileges.

The relationship between JWT auth and the Enterprise API is one of convenience. Enterprise API apps are often non-interactive server-side scripts and/or scaled out to multiple processes. In these scenarios JWT is much easier to work with than 3-Legged OAuth.